# Private static properties in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

If I do something like this below, how can I access the property out the class?

```
class Person
{
    private static name: string;
}

console.log(Person.name);
```

Shouldn't it inaccessible?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It should be an error but isn't. From the spec, section 8.2.1:

> It is not possible to specify the accessibility of statics—they are effectively always public.

Accessibility modifiers on statics are something the team has considered in the past. If you have a strong use case you should bring this up on [codeplex](http://typescript.codeplex.com) site!

Comment: It's certainly possible to indicate the *intent* of private static - that's to say you'll get a compile error if you try and access a private static field outside of the containing class. As per the spec: "Private and protected accessibility is enforced only at compile-time and serves as no more than an indication of intent".

Comment: @eddiewould the intent itself is confusing though, to me at least. I'm not really sure why you would want both.

Answer (score 6):

```
class Person
{
    private static theName: string = "John";
    static get name():string{
        return Person.theName;
    }
}

console.log(Person.name);
```

If a static property is private we need to provide a static get method to access it. This may not be a common solution but it is the only way I know of to directly access a private static property. On the other hand, you may have to add a second get method if you also intend to access the property from an instantiated object. Both get methods can have the same name since the static get method will be invisible to the instantiated object.

Answer (score 1):

Well, not really, in fact you can. Maybe most important is to ask about the TypeScript *version* it relates. I have **v1.5 beta**, part of my VS2012 installation (yes, it works despite it is targeted at VS2013).

I have a class like this:

```
class ItemListPreProcessor {

    private static names: string[] = [ 'Name', 'Age' ];

    static createHeader = (eltName: string) => {
        var pdiv = $(eltName);
        pdiv.html('<table><thead><tr></tr></thead></tr><tbody></tbody></table>');
        var row = $('tr', pdiv);
        ItemListPreProcessor.names.forEach((n) => {
            row.append('<th>' + n + '</th>');
        });
        return $('tbody', pdiv);
    };
}
```

In the sample above you can see both `private` and `static`. The class is compiled to the following JavaScript:

```
var ItemListPreProcessor = (function () {
    function ItemListPreProcessor() {
    }
    ItemListPreProcessor.names = ['Name', 'Age'];

    ItemListPreProcessor.createHeader = function (eltName) {
        var pdiv = $(eltName);
        pdiv.html('<table><thead><tr></tr></thead></tr><tbody></tbody></table>');
        var row = $('tr', pdiv);
        ItemListPreProcessor.names.forEach(function (n) {
            row.append('<th>' + n + '</th>');
        });
        return $('tbody', pdiv);
    };
    return ItemListPreProcessor;
})();
```

and there's no problem with either compiling it (this you see), as well as executing it (this you should trust, or, if you like, try).

Comment: It may compile, but it's not actually private. This is frustrating because javascript itself does indeed support this functionality.

Comment: It is private in TypeScript, this is what is important, that is, you cannot access the static private  outside the class, which is the intention. How this is translated to Javascript is out of the scope of my answer to Brian. And, to be precise, when we have to state something let's specify to which language it relates. Otherwise we may fall into endless debates, leading to nowhere.

Comment: Well, I disagree that it's "what is important", and I'm not sure how it's "outside the scope of" your answer, since you show compiled javascript in your answer as proof that it works. I was simply pointing out what you omitted. It may compile without error, but it in fact is not private in javascript.

Comment: So, you say that you care about the compilation results? (To be correct transpilation results.) I don't. This makes things move ahead, I am not interested in what exactly CLR or JVM instructions the C# or Java source is compiled, I am interested in the Java/C# source code itself, 
and, of course the results of its execution.

Comment: "The results of its execution" is the part you may want to think a little more about, especially when we are talking about javascript, in the browser. If you were writing an SDK, for instance, and you expected a variable to be `private static`, but in fact the consumer could not only access but modify that variable/property, you might run into some issues, to say the least.

Comment: But I don't! **The question is about TypeScript** - take a look again. "The result of execution" is the result of some executable code **run somewhere**, not some source code **referenced somewhere**. Javascript has only illustrative purpose here - to show that the TypeScript gets transpilated, no more, no less, otherwise I may have shown a blank window saying only something like "Compiled!". So, you see that I am **not interested in Javascript whatsoever**, which belongs to the past. Hope this makes things clear.

Comment: Time for editing my answer ended... By "belongs to the past" I meant the way it is now. No wonder so many transpilers, super-set languages, etc. emerged. Believing that Javascript as it is now will survive all these  is naive. In this respect TypeScript adopts and supports ECMA Committee standardization efforts. This is why it is important to take it so seriously and look in the future, and also, this is why I am not interested in Javascript anymore.