# Why can't I declare local variables and functions within a TypeScript class?

Tags: javascript, typescript

In TypeScript, I can't seem to declare a function in a class without the compiler adding it to the prototype. For example:

```
class MyTypeScriptClass {
    // method, is added to prototype
    foo1(): void {
        alert('invoked foo1');
    }

    // private method also added to prototype
    private foo2(): void {
        alert('invoked foo2');
    }

    //// can I have a local function, without making it a private method?
    //function foo3() {
    //    alert('invoked foo3');
    //}
}
```

The above compiles to this:

```
var MyTypeScriptClass = (function () {
    function MyTypeScriptClass() { }
    MyTypeScriptClass.prototype.foo1 = function () {
        alert('invoked foo1');
    };
    MyTypeScriptClass.prototype.foo2 = function () {
        alert('invoked foo2');
    };
    return MyTypeScriptClass;
})();
```

What I am looking for is typescript that can compile to the following JavaScript:

```
var fvm = new FlasherViewModel2();
    var MyTypeScriptClass = (function () {
        function MyTypeScriptClass() { }
        MyTypeScriptClass.prototype.foo1 = function () {
            alert('invoked foo1');
        };
        MyTypeScriptClass.prototype.foo2 = function () {
            alert('invoked foo2');
        };
        function foo3() {
            alert('invoked foo3');
        }
        return MyTypeScriptClass;
    })();
```

**Can it be done?**

(As a side note, I know that foo3 would not be callable from external code. I would actually invoke foo3 from another method within the class, for example, to pass a function to a jQuery fadeOut.)

Comment: You want a private function that is only accessible to the instances of a particular class? That sounds like a `private static`, which is not possible according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827544/private-static-properties-in-typescript). If you wanted `foo3` to be public, would simply making it a `static` work for you?

Comment: Yes, I was looking for a private function that was only accessible to instances. Thanks for the link & clarification. I was able to achieve the same goal by using a pointer function (lambda), because the issue I was trying to deal with was losing the outer `this` reference in an inner-scoped function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As apsillers mentions, `private static` is probably what you want. While it's not supported in current builds, you will be able to have a `private static` member in TypeScript at some point in the future (the design team changed its mind on this one based on feedback similar to this).

Answer (score 2):

I just discovered another way to have private methods in a typescript class, though the pattern may smell a little funny. As far as I can tell, you can only do this when you wrap the class in a `module`. For example:

```
module MyApp {
    // not accessible externally, `this` must be passed in if needed
    function foo3(that: MyTypeScriptClass): void {
        that.foo1();
        alert('invoked foo3');
    }

    // not accessible externally
    function foo4(): void {
        alert('invoked foo4');
    }

    export class MyTypeScriptClass {
        // normal method, is added to prototype
        foo1(): void {
            alert('invoked foo1');
        }

        // private method also added to prototype, is accessible externally
        private foo2(): void {
            alert('invoked foo2');
            foo3(this);
            foo4();
        }
    }
}
```

The above compiles into:

```
var MyApp;
(function (MyApp) {
    function foo3(that) {
        that.foo1();
        alert('invoked foo3');
    }
    function foo4() {
        alert('invoked foo4');
    }
    var MyTypeScriptClass = (function () {
        function MyTypeScriptClass() { }
        MyTypeScriptClass.prototype.foo1 = function () {
            alert('invoked foo1');
        };
        MyTypeScriptClass.prototype.foo2 = function () {
            alert('invoked foo2');
            foo3(this);
            foo4();
        };
        return MyTypeScriptClass;
    })();
    MyApp.MyTypeScriptClass = MyTypeScriptClass;    
})(MyApp || (MyApp = {}));
```

With the above, external javascript could invoke `foo2()` on an instance of `MyTypeScriptClass`, but neither `foo3()` nor `foo4()` is accessible externally at runtime. The biggest caveat is that if your private method needs access to members of the instance, you have to pass `this` in as a function parameter. Essentially, these are private static methods.

```
var instance = new MyApp.MyTypeScriptClass();

// public, accessible externally
instance.foo1();

// will not compile in a .ts file, but works at runtime from manual js file
instance.foo2();

// runtime exception, foo3 is not defined
foo3(instance);
MyApp.foo3(instance);

// runtime exception, foo4 is not defined
foo4();
MyApp.foo4();
```

This approach also sort of works with scalar variables, but the variables are also essentially static -- you can't have different values for different class instances. To do that, as far as I can tell, you still need to declare them within the class. Marking them `private` will keep the typescript compiler from allowing external calls to them, but other javascript code can still access them externally.